# Different Colors in hint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am using `TextInputLayout` for hint in an `EditText`.

Now, I want to give a hint to the `TextInputLayout` with 2 colors.

Like in the image shown :

[image]

Is this possible? i have tried adding the text in html format but it is not working.

Code for the edittext :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/pv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Property Value"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/HintText"

            >
            <com.app.aspirehomeloans.FontClass.Edittext_RobotoRegular
                android:id="@+id/login_emailid"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textSize="@dimen/edittext_size"
                android:paddingTop="3dp"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:paddingBottom="3dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/edittextcolor"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:text=""
                android:nextFocusDown="@+id/login_password"

                />
            <View
            android:id="@+id/login_email_line"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/divercolor"
                />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: if i am not wrong you are trying to achieve user input text color and hint color diffrent..right?

Comment: I am trying to acheive 2 different color in one hint. like seen in image "Constructed Area (SQFT)" is in different color and "*" is in different color

Comment: did you try with my answer??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html) to achieve that, something like this should work :

**#1** First set the hint in your `xml` file for ex : "Property Value"

**#2** Then use this method to add the red asterisk to the hint :

```
private void addRedAsterisk(EditText editText){
    String text = editText.getHint().toString();
    String asterisk = " *";
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    builder.append(text);
    int start = builder.length();
    builder.append(asterisk);
    int end = builder.length();
    builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end,
            Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    editText.setHint(builder);
}
```

**UPDATE**

As you're using a `TextInputLayout` this method won't work as
currently setting different colors in hint is not supported in `TextInputLayout`.

However, you can get partial results using the following class i.e, you will get the **red** asterisk when the `hint` is in expanded state but not when it is collapsed :

```
public class HintColorHelper {

    public static void setUpHintColor(EditText editText, TextInputLayout textInputLayout){
        textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(0);
        String hint = textInputLayout.getHint().toString();
        final SpannableStringBuilder hintWithAsterisk = getHintWithAsterisk(hint);
        if(!editText.hasFocus()){
            textInputLayout.setHint(null);
            editText.setHint(hintWithAsterisk);
        }
        setOnFocuschangeListener(editText, textInputLayout, hintWithAsterisk);
    }

    private static void setOnFocuschangeListener(final EditText editText, final TextInputLayout textInputLayout, final SpannableStringBuilder hintWithAsterisk){
        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus) {
                    textInputLayout.setHint(hintWithAsterisk);
                    editText.setHint(null);
                } else if(editText.getText().toString().length()==0){
                    textInputLayout.setHint(null);
                    editText.setHint(hintWithAsterisk);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static SpannableStringBuilder getHintWithAsterisk(String hint){
        String asterisk = " *";
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
        builder.append(hint);
        int start = builder.length();
        builder.append(asterisk);
        int end = builder.length();
        builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        return builder;
    }
}
```

To use this, simply use the static method `setUpHintColor(editText, textInputLayout)` of the `HintColorHelper` class like this :

```
HintColorHelper.setUpHintColor(yourEditText, yourTextInputLayout);
```

Here's the output :

- [Collapsed state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIghq.jpg)
- [Expanded state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Oh9J.jpg)

Comment: but i have set the hint to InputTextLayout

Comment: then you can use `TextInputLayout` instead of `EditText` in the above code

Comment: When i use TextInputLayout then it dosent change. only a * is added. not in different Color. i have used your code

Answer (score 2):

**Try this code**

```
String text = "<font color=#307575>Property</font> <font color=#bdd95b> Value</font>";

 TextInputLayout textInputLayoutObj = (TextInputLayout)findViewById(R.id.text_input_layout_id);
 textInputLayoutObj .setHint(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: not working. already tried this. adding the hint to textinputlayout.

Comment: yes, this is not working. Please try it yourself and tell me if it works then send me the xml code as well as the java code. Please

Comment: @ParthAnjaria  okay

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can not do that using xml,you need to do that programmatically,and i suggest you to use Spanabble String

```
TextView textvw = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);

String txthint = "Property value ";
String astrk= "*";
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(txthint);
int start = builder.length();
builder.append(astrk);
int end = builder.length();

builder.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), start, end, 
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

textvw .setText(builder);
```

Comment: it is not working @Aditya . As i need to add hint to InputTextLayout not edittext, otherwise this code is functinal if i neet to add text to textview